# Can you apply metamagic to a Wished spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, metamagic, wish

The [*wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) spell enables you to emulate any spell of 8th level or lower.

Can a sorcerer apply a [metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic) effect to the emulated spell by spending the appropriate number of sorcery points (provided that he knows said metamagic effect)?

For example, could he cast *wish* and spend sorcery points to use Extended Spell on his casting of [*death ward*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/death-ward)?

Answer (score 15):

## RAW: No metamagic can be applied to *wish*-duplicated spell effects except empowered (RAI disagrees)

#### Wish duplicates other spells, it  doesn't cast them

Wish states that you can use it to:

> ...**duplicate the effect** of any other spell of 8th level or lower. You
> don't need to meet the requirements of that spell, it simply **takes
> effect**.

Note that it doesn't say anything about the fact that you are *casting* the spell. You aren't. You are casting *wish* and as the effect, getting the effects of another spell.

The rules for metamagic say:

> You can only use one Metamagic option on a spell **when you cast it**, unless otherwise noted.

And every metamagic option except *empowered spell* begins with:

> When you cast a spell...

Thus, you *could* apply metamagic to *wish*, but it would only apply to the duration and other characteristics of *wish* itself (since that is what you are casting), not the spell whose effects it is duplicating. At the exact time of casting *wish* only has the characteristics (range, duration, etc.) listed for *wish* and not the spell it is duplicating.

This effectively means that you can only apply Quickened Spell and Subtle Spell to *wish*, neither of which will affect the duplicated spell's effects. The only effect would be to be able to cast *wish* itself as a bonus action and without somatic or verbal components respectively.

#### Empowered Spell *will* work for any spell that *wish* duplicates that does damage

Empowered Spell says:

> When you roll damage for a spell...

There are no other requirements than this, and this can clearly only be applied *after* the spell is cast and does not depend on having actually cast it. Thus, you can still empower any spell damage resulting from a *wish*-duplicated spell.

#### You can always *wish* for a metamagicked spell

Another option would be of course simply to *wish* for a spell with its metamagic effects. However, this would be outside the realm of duplicating a spell and into the custom *wish* territory. Thus it would come with the 33% chance of never being able to cast *wish* again.

## RAI: Yes you can apply metamagic to *wish*-duplicated spells

Jeremy Crawford appears to differ on this interpretation in this Tweet:

> Q: Can you Twin a spell duplicated with Wish? And if you do, how many sorcery points do you use.
>
> A: Yes, and use the number of points appropriate for the level of the spell you are duplicating.

And again in the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=5):

> **Can my sorcerer use Twinned Spell on a spell duplicated by the casting of a *wish* spell? And if so, how many sorcery points does it cost?** Yes, you can. It costs the number of sorcery points appropriate for the level of the spell you’re duplicating.

It isn't really clear what logic JC uses to support this answer. It is possible he is implying that *wish* does actually result in the duplicated effects being cast, but that does not appear to follow the RAW. This might also have an impact on other effects that depend on the spell being "cast". But, if it makes more sense to you and your DM/table prefers, this ruling is there to be used.

Comment: You should expand/rephrase that "RAI" acronym ;)

Comment: I want to +1 this, but as far as I'm concerned, Sage Advice is RAW. It says it's contents are official rulings. So Jeremy Crawford's tweet would be RAI, but the Sage Advice ruling is inaccurately called RAI here.

Answer (score 6):

## Yes.

Despite the rules excluding Wish from being **Twinned**, due to its range of **self**, the [Sage Advice Compendium](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=5) explicitly confirms this:

> **Can my sorcerer use Twinned Spell on a spell duplicated by the casting of a *wish* spell? And if so, how many sorcery points does it cost?**
>
> Yes, you can. It costs the number of sorcery points appropriate for the level of the spell you’re duplicating.

This doesn't seem to fall under RaW, as [Wish](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Wish#content) is described as

> **Wish**
>
> *9th level conjuration*
>
> Casting Time: 1 action
>
> **Range: Self**

And Twinned Spell requires:

> When you cast a spell that targets only one creature and **doesn’t have a range of self**,

but apparently Wish is a special case. By Sage Advice, you can at least Twin or Empower a Wish-based spell. I would discuss with your DM what rulings he prefers to follow, and go from there.

Answer (score -1):

### No, because you aren't casting the spell.

You can't metamagic the Death Ward because you must cast the spell yourself to use metamagic. Most of the metamagic options explicitly say "when you cast a spell", and there's a general restriction that "you can use only one metamagic option on a spell when you cast it".

You also can't metamagic the Wish to increase *its* duration, because Extended requires the spell to have a duration of one minute, and Wish's duration is zero. (Similarly, Careful, for example, requires the spell to allow a saving throw to reduce damage, and Wish doesn't have one.)

(The argument could be made that when Wish duplicates another spell, it takes on that spell's properties including its duration. I would respond that you have to Extend the spell *when you cast it*, at which point it's still Wish.)

When you cast Wish you're saying "Hey, universe, gimme a Death Ward!" and it happens, because you're an umpteenth-level wizard and the universe does what you say. But that's not the same as creating the Death Ward yourself. You lose a little bit of control.

Comment: What about empowered? All it requires is to roll damage for a spell, wouldn't that count?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Also quickened, heightened, etc

Comment: @thedarkwanderer: Actually both of those say "when you cast a spell..."

Comment: So in other words, you can only apply metamagic effects to the casting of Wish, not the spell it emulates. Thus, the only valid metamagics on a Wish are Quickened and Subtle (and maybe Empowered if you emulate a damaging spell, but not sure about that).

Comment: Or asking directly for the same effect as a metamagicked spell, which wouldn’t cost sorcery points, wouldn’t require being a sorcerer, but would bring the 33% risk.

Comment: Can't I wish "Hey, universe, gimme an _extended_ Death Ward!"?

Comment: @AguinaldoSilvestre Sure, but you'd suffer the stress effects of doing something other than replicating an existing spell. (Changing a spell's duration can make it a significantly different spell.)