# Can a multiclassed Wizard/Sorcerer use the Twinned Spell metamagic option on Simulacrum?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, sorcerer, metamagic

Consider a Wizard 13/Sorcerer 7 multiclass, who happens to have the Twinned Spell [metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic) option:

> When you cast a spell that targets only one creature and doesn’t have a range of self, you can spend a number of sorcery points equal to the spell’s level to target a second creature in range with the same spell (1 sorcery point if the spell is a cantrip).
>
> To be eligible, a spell must be incapable of targeting more than one creature at the spell’s current level. For example, *magic missile* and *scorching ray* aren’t eligible, but *ray of frost* and *chromatic orb* are.

Now this character casts *simulacrum*:

1. **Can a Sorcerer use Twinned Spell to create 2 duplicates of himself
   (or someone else)?**
2. **Can a Sorcerer use Twinned Spell to create 1 duplicate for 2
   different targets at the same time?**

Comment: [This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128061/can-you-apply-metamagic-to-a-wished-spell) is VERY related to this one.

Comment: @BlueMoon93 Agree, theoretical application of Twinned Spell to *Simulacrum* is possible with Wiz-13/Sorc-7 multiclass, no *Wish* is needed.

Comment: I edited the question to focus on the Twinned/Simulacrum aspect

Comment: Since the MC option and the wish option are two very different questions and the latter already has an answer elsewhere I have edited this to only focus on the MC.

Comment: This needs to be two separate questions. (And IMO both are good questions).  That SA didn't get into published SA Compendium, so it can't be viewed as an official ruling, though it is good to understand the RAI from that dev ...

Comment: Of note, for those citing Sage Advice: simulacrum is not addressed in [the published sage advice compendium](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf).  SA excerpts that are included there are official rulings, as noted in that article.

Comment: @AlexMillette does the current form of the question ask what you intended it to?

Comment: Yes it does, although I'm probably more concerned about that matter about Twinned Wish now, But this is of course for another question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Yes, Simulacrum can be twinned

#### It creates one duplicate each of two creatures.

Just to take the first line of the Simulacrum spell:

> You shape an illusory duplicate of one beast or humanoid that is within range for the entire casting time of the spell.

The target is one beast or humanoid within range touch.

There's nothing logically stopping this from working. Simulacrum doesn't target self or more than one creature.

And to pull out a line of the Twinned Spell feature:

> [snip] ... target a second creature in range ... [snip]

If you had two people (one of which could be yourself) within the range of "touch" for 12 hours and you have the sorcery points (you'll need seven), then you should be able to twin the spell and create two duplicates: one of each creature.

Also as a restriction of Twinned Spell, a twinned *simulacrum* can not be used to create two duplicates of the same creature.

So, to answer your questions succinctly:

1. No, a twinned *simulacrum* must target different creatures.
2. Yes.

Comment: I know this is old, but are you sure? I was just on Sage advice and found someone asking about creating two simulacrums. Jeremy Crawford simply pointed out to the last line of the spell that says you can only have one. Wouldn't that mean that, while Simulacrum does fit the Twinned Spell requirements, it would be useless as only one of the snow clones would actually be able to exist? https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/03/13/can-you-have-more-than-one-simulacrum-active-at-one-time/

Answer (score 8):

## You can twin Simulacrum, and create a duplicate of a target, and a duplicate of a second target.

Simulacrum falls under Twinned Spell requirements, and now targets 2 creatures. It's the same as if you had cast Simulacrum twice, with different targets, except the first duplicate does not disappear.

Answer (score 2):

### Probably not for the twin Simulacrum

Simulacrum isn't a creature until after the spell takes effect.

> You shape an illusory duplicate of one beast or humanoid that is
> within range for the entire casting time of the spell. *The duplicate
> is a creature*, partially real and formed from ice or snow, and it can
> take actions and otherwise be affected as a normal creature. (SRD, p. 180)

What the sorcerer is casting the spell on is a bunch of objects, not a creature, that become a creature.

> (snow or ice in quantities sufficient to made a life-­‐‑size copy of the duplicated creature; some hair, fingernail clippings, or other piece of that creature’s body placed inside the snow or ice; and powdered ruby worth 1,500  gp, sprinkled over the duplicate and consumed by the spell) (SRD p. 180)

Twin needs to be cast on a creature, specifically, per the rules you cited.  With that in mind ...

#### Maybe you can (what is being touched?)

With a range of *touch*, it is unclear whether or not that which is to be duplicated must be touched or not.  If yes, then provided that sufficient material is present, then the sorcerer is "touching" a creature and thus makes two duplicates of that creature.  (thanks to @AlexMillette for that point)

I can see the ruling going either way, so discuss with your DM.  The issue to resolve is "what it is that the caster is touching in order to create the simulacrum?  The pile of material, or the creature to be duplicated?"

As an aside, [regarding "touching" for touch spells and abilities](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/819294828659806208), how the touch is to be executed isn't precisely defined.  (A JCrawford tweet).

Comment: "You shape an illusory duplicate of one beast or humanoid that is within range for the entire casting time of the spell." This seems to imply that the "Touch" range refers to the targeted original, which is certainly a creature.

Comment: I see his point, although I highly doubt it was intended in this way. The range is "touch" and the creature to be duplicated has to stay within that range for the duration of the cast. This begs the question as to how do you craft a snowman while groping your victim? I think it is another example of horrible wording, or trying to copy a previous version.

Comment: @AlexMillette Interesting point, so I folded that in. Good catch.

Comment: I get a feeling these should be two separate answers... whether the components or the original creature should be considered the target completely changes which answer you get.

Comment: @Erik I appreciate your point, but I find more appealing the 5e approach of ruling over rules when the text doesn't specify;

Comment: Wrt your last sentence, what edit was it that made this question contain two questions? I'm not seeing where that happened but I may be missing something.

Comment: Great answer. It might be worth noting that there's a [tweet by Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/819294828659806208) indicating that spells or effects which require you to "touch" a target don't necessarily require a free hand (so a Paladin could Lay on Hands without needing to put down a sword or shield).

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme I slipped it in there as an aside. Thanks.  (We have a paladin player who may find that ruling of interest)