# When I cast Glyph of Warding, can I use Wish to supply the second spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-slots, wish, traps

Assuming I do **not** have access to a second 9th level spell for that day (such as via a Boon, a scroll, or an item), when I cast [*glyph of warding*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding) at a lower level than 9th, can I use [*wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) to supply the second spell?

The key considerations I am thinking about are that if I replicate a spell using [*wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish), that spell is cast using a 9th level slot; that, and the highest level spell that a [*glyph of warding*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding) can store is equal to the level of the spell slot it was cast with.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Good question. Technically you could upcast *glyph of warding* to raise the limit of the spell level you can store in it... But you'd still be unable to both upcast to 9th level and cast *wish* unless you had two 9th-level slots.

Comment: These questions might help a bit: "[At what level are spells duplicated by the Wish spell cast?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/164645)" and "[Can you use Wish to duplicate a spell at a higher level?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50258)"

Answer (score 3):

### No, for several reasons.

Here's *glyph of warding*:

> You can store a prepared spell of 3rd level or lower in the glyph by casting it as part of creating the glyph...

The first problem is that a spell created via *wish* is not a prepared spell. (*Wish* itself is, but it's not the spell you're storing in the glyph.)

The second problem is that you have to actually cast the spell, and *wish* doesn't cast spells; it duplicates them.

Casting a spell requires performing the components. The rules are fairly emphatic about this:

> A spell's components are the physical requirements you must meet in order to cast it... If you can't provide one or more of a spell's components, you are unable to cast the spell.

And specifically for material components:

> But if a cost is indicated for a component, a character must have that specific component before he or she can cast the spell. If a spell states that a material component is consumed by the spell, the caster must provide this component for each casting of the spell.

*Wish* bypasses all of this, including the requirement to provide specific material components, and that's because it **doesn't cast the spell**. The verb it uses is "duplicate".

The third problem is that *wish* says that "the spell simply takes effect". But *glyph of warding* precisely requires the spell not to take effect just yet. It overrides the normal mechanics of casting the spell, but it doesn't override wishing the effect into existence.

Comment: As I'm sure you know, it is not agreed upon whether duplicating a spell with *wish* counts as casting that spell ([link](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/144884)). That said, any spell created/duplicated/cast by *wish* is not a prepared spell, so I think that part of your argument is honestly convincing enough.

Comment: @Medix2 That's an interesting link. Thanks! Though if the duplicated spell is cast via *wish* (as I think it is), then there's no need for it to be prepared. *Glyph of warding* only requires that the spell is *cast*.

Comment: @Cleric No, _glyph of warding_ says "You can store a *prepared spell*".

Comment: @MarkWells What's a prepared spell? I think that needs more elaboration. For example, I believe it's feasible to store a spell from a scroll, a magic item, or an innate racial ability into a *glyph of warding*, but I dont believe there is a rule that specifically lists these as "prepared spells." Furthermore, that spell is in the bard spell list, and they are not casters who prepare their spells like clerics or wizards, so it can't mean a spell that you prepare in that way. Bards have spells known, not spells prepared.

Comment: The term "prepared" here could be just a plain English word meaning "ready," and if so, having the *wish* spell might mean every spell of 8th level or lower is prepared for you, as in you are ready to use those spells.

Comment: When I said "there's no need for it to be prepared" above, I was thinking (I think the same as you) that it needed to be a spell in your spell list that you've selected to learn, but after I considered all the potential sources where spells might come from, I realized that it wasn't a sufficiently wide enough definition.

Comment: Glyph of Warding has another function that doesn't require casting a prepared spell. Bards get access to that.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes you can

Jeremy Crawford tweeted the [following](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/01/16/when-wish-is-used-to-duplicate-a-spell-can-it-be-duplicated-at-a-higher-level/).

> A spell you duplicate with wish can be cast at a higher level, as long
>   as that level is no higher than 8th.

The wording of **Wish** for casting other spells is:

> *The basic use of this spell is to duplicate any other spell of 8th
>   level or lower. You don't need to meet any requirements in that spell,
>   including costly components. The spell simply takes effect.*

Glyph of Warding have the following phrase:

> **Spell Glyph.** *You can store a prepared spell of 3rd level or lower in
>   the glyph by casting it as part of creating the glyph. [...] If you create a spell glyph, you can store any spell of up to the same level as the slot you use for the glyph of warding.*

For example, you can cast **Glyph** at 5th level, then use **Wish** to cast **Planar Binding**, **Wish** would null the material cost of **Planar Binding**.

Just remember that **Wish** can only replicate spells up to 8th level. So you could use your 8th level slot to cast **Glyph** then use **Wish** to store any 8th level or lower spell.

Comment: Firstly, [Jeremy Crawford's tweets are no longer considered official rulings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/140221/41726), so you should add some more support for your premise ([like what can be found in this related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50258/41726)). Secondly, I'd like to see some more of your logical extension. It is not clear to me the connection between being able to replicate higher level spells, and being able to use *wish* as a proxy for the casting of the stored spell.

Comment: Now I am a little confused. If Wish states "You don't need to meet any requirements in that spell, including costly components. The spell simply takes effect."
Does it mean that I can use Glyph via Wish and have any spell stored in it?

Comment: That question is answered here: [Does wishing a spell glyph into existence also require casting the stored spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/136580/41726)